# Testlink esperiencing MySQL error in testcase_script_links

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, testlink

I try to install testLink but i experiencie one error :

```
TestLink setup will now attempt to setup the database:

Creating connection to Database Server:OK!

Connecting to database `testlink`:OK!
Creating Testlink DB user `testLinkUser`:OK! ( ok - new user)
Processing:sql/mysql/testlink_create_tables.sql

  ============================================================================== 

DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START 

ATTENTION: Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness (CWE-200) 

        Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 

        issue to development TEAM. 

============================================================================== 

#0  database->exec_query(CREATE TABLE /*prefix*/testcase_script_links (
  `tcversion_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `project_key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `repository_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `code_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `branch_name` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `commit_id` varchar(40) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tcversion_id`,`project_key`,`repository_name`,`code_path`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8) called at [C:\serveur\wamp64\www\testlink\install\sqlParser.class.php:98]
#1  SqlParser->process(sql/mysql/testlink_create_tables.sql) called at [C:\serveur\wamp64\www\testlink\install\installNewDB.php:445]
```

I have the lastest version of PhpMyAdmin, i use wampserver64 with mysql 5.7.14
I don't understand why this crash.
I've read some tell the error can be cause by timestamp, but i don't have timestamp here...

Thanks for any tips or help

Answer (score 0):

All work now, i use another testlink install and it's ok.

I have use the git repo, and now the real install files.

http://testlink.org/

Here, the first link work.
The git repo files don't work.